# Read JSON Payload as it is for a boolean type

Tags: java, json

**JSON - JACKSON - Parser Issue :**

Problem: When user passes 0 for a boolean variable in a JSON Payload parser constructs it as `FALSE`, if client passes any value greater than zero I am getting `TRUE` in my POJO. My need is I have to / JACKSON Parser have to throw error for any value except - `TRUE`/`true`/`FALSE`/`false` for the Boolean variable in my POJO.

JACKSON JAXB parser throws error for any boolean variable if user passes like - "abc"/"1234" but not numeric numbers i.e it accepts 0/1/123 etc…

How to set parsers to throw errors for numbers?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can throw a custom exception in the setter if value is anything but true or false in case you are using Jackson binding with Java bean

Comment: Corrected grammar, light formatting

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem simply lied in customizing Serializing DeSerializing behavior of the Jackson Library.
In the constructor we can provide deserializing configuration(s) along with customized deserializers.

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
         }     
}
```

Prepare an object of the SimpleDeserializers.

```
SimpleDeserializers simpleDeserializers = new SimpleDeserializers();
```

Now we would prepare a boolean deserializer for the same, our customized one.

```
private class BooleanDeserializer&lt;T extends Object&gt; extends
 JsonDeserializer&lt;Boolean&gt; {
 final protected Class&lt;?&gt; _valueClass = Boolean.class;

@Override
 public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
 throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return _parseBooleanPrimitive2(jp, ctxt);
 }

protected final boolean _parseBooleanPrimitive2(JsonParser jp,
 DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
 JsonProcessingException {
 JsonToken t = jp.getCurrentToken();
 if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE) {
 return true;
 }
 if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE) {
 return false;
 }
 if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
 String text = jp.getText().trim();
 if ("true".equals(text)) {
 return true;
 }
 if ("false".equals(text)) {
 return Boolean.FALSE;
 }

throw ctxt.weirdStringException(_valueClass,
 "only \"true\" or \"false\" recognized");
 }
 // Otherwise, no can do:
 throw ctxt.mappingException(_valueClass);
 }
 }
```

This boolean deserializer is a generified class subclassing the JsonDeserializer, which is supplied to handle the deserialization of the values which are generally not supported by the default boolean  deserializer.

Comment: Thank you Tanvi, can you a bit more specific with Java code, Like, I am not sure how/where to  use   "SimpleDeserializers simpleDeserializers = new SimpleDeserializers()" can you add clear Java code here pls? also you are referring to use this new class as cfg in my mapper class ?  ObjectMapper().setDeserializationConfig("cfg")